# What does it really mean to take correlation between time series?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, parameter-estimation, correlation, time-series

I have a conceptual problem when we extend the correlation to time series. I understand probability and statistics as a two way route. Either I begin from a random variable (r.v.) $X$ and sample from its probability distribution, or I observe a sample of values $x_1,...,x_n$ drawn from that distribution and I infer something about the distribution of the r.v. $X$.

When I have two r.v. $X$ and $Y$, I can establish the correlation between them (theoretically, based on an expected value). If I have the observations (samples) $x_1,...,x_n$ and $y_1,...,y_n$, I can estimate the correlation from the specified formula.

When I have a time series, though I have timed indexed observations $x_1,..,x_n$ which are not a sample, because at each time I observe a different r.v. A random process is a function $X(\omega, t)$, and for every state $\omega$ I have a whole trajectory. How am I supposed to conceptualize a correlation between two trajectories?

Here lies the problem: I get that autoccorelation can give me information regarding the dependence between each time point and the next (with lag one), but don't really get how we interpret this in general, or even if we should call it the same. I can't grasp the probabilistic meaning of taking the correlation (sample) of two time series, when there is no single r.v. that is being observed (different from the usual correlation used in a static context), or if this would only have probabilistic meaning under the assumption of strong stationarity, in which at every time point $x_t$ I have equal distribution?

To illustrate a little further, I will reference my previous question in this same line, regarding the meaning of generating two correlated brownian paths: [Understanding correlation in the context of a time series, simulation and brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4814463/understanding-correlation-in-the-context-of-a-time-series-simulation-and-browni). Also, I want to point simulation, because it shows that only when I simulate multiple scnearios (Take trajectories as columns of a matrix) I am able to estimate the correlation of two r.v. $X_{t_i}$ and $X_{t_j}$ (taking correlation between rows $i$ and $j$), because only then I have a sample of each r.v.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make your question more concise? You currently have several close votes saying your question "needs more focus"

Comment: @JoseAvilez Thank you, where can I see those votes? I was not aware. I edited the question again. Not sure if I can make it shorter.

Comment: Your rep needs to be above a certain threshold to see close votes. The answer to your question is really about what parameter is your estimator is trying to estimate. Since time series can be arbitrarily complex, one usually imposes parametric restrictions. After that you can talk about whether certain estimators (e.g. sample correlation) are good estimators for certain parameters (e.g. correlation of two time series, e.g. in the case correlation doesn't depend on $t$)

Comment: I am refering to correlation. In my cited question I mention that there is a way in which I can simulate two brownian motions with a specified correlation. It is that kind of meaning that I do not get. There is no two r.v. being compared, but two trajectories in time. At each of those times, there are different r.v. being observed (the variance and expected value changes)

Comment: Best to ask your question again, concisely, so that the community doesn't close it. In the case of Brownian motion, when people discuss its correlation they mean $\langle B, W \rangle_t = \rho t$. If you take the correlation of the paths you get a really bad estimator for $\rho$ (in fact, it's not even consistent), so instead you should look at the correlation of the increments, which will now be IID across time. Like I said, it really is problem specific and one should take care in designing estimators.